# $watch to monitor change in class on directive firing 1 cycle late

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My goal is to do some action when a particular directive receives the class 'focused' through ng-class.
But watching for changes on each of the directives seems to be doing weird things I don't understand. Here is the code first:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6Te8O2mlBI058DpwGF7f?p=preview

**index.html**

```
   <test-question
      ng-class="{'focused': tracer.focus == 1}"
      focusnum = "{{n}}"
      ng-click="tracer.focus = 1"
      >
      Test Question 1
    </test-question>
    <test-question
      ng-class="{'focused': tracer.focus == 2}"
      focusnum = "{{n}}"
      ng-click="tracer.focus = 2"
      >
      Test Question 2
    </test-question>
    <test-question
      ng-class="{'focused': tracer.focus == 3}"
      focusnum = "{{n}}"
      ng-click="tracer.focus = 3"
      >
      Test Question 3
    </test-question>
```

**script.js**

```
angular.module('sampleApp', [])
  .controller("SampleController", function($scope) {
    $scope.tracer = {
        focus: 1
    }
  })
  .directive('testQuestion', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
          $scope.$watch(function() {
                  return el.attr('class');
              }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                  // do something here when directive gets class focused
                  console.log("text", el.text());
                  console.log("newValue", newValue);
                  console.log("oldValue", oldValue);
            });
        }
    }
  });
```

Initially the first test question is highlighted. When you click the second question I expect the console to log

`"text" Test Question 1
"newValue" undefined
"oldValue" focused
"text" Test Question 2
"newValue" focused
"oldValue" undefined`

However the console actually logs

`"text" Test Question 1
"newValue" focused
"oldValue" undefined`

**As a result, of this weird behavior I cannot accurately detect when a directive receives the class focused. It appears as if the watch is one cycle late. It would be great if a fellow friend could help me understand why this is happening. Thank you!**

*Additional*

After I click question 2, and if I subsequently click question 3 the console logs

`"text" Test Question 1
"newValue"
"oldValue" focused
"text" Test Question 2
"newValue" focused
"oldValue" undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes is become late, there is no proper solution for this condition yet. However you can do something below.

```
    $scope.$watch(function() {
              return el.hasClass('focused');
          }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
              // now you should use javascript setTimeout for check after $diggest
              var myOldValue = newValue; //this mean newValue realy oldValue yet.
               setTimeout(function(){
                 var myNewValue= el.hasClass('focused');
                  console.log(myNewValue, myOldValue)
                  //do staff here
               },0)
              //note that, don't use angular $timeout it may couse recursive stack
        });
```

**WHY?**

Because you are watching an async  event which outside of AngularJS. Namely need to called at the end, to tell AngularJS that an asynchronous event just occurred by using $scope.$apply().

This like our custom **$('button').on('click', ...)** events which need to **$scope.$apply()**. However you may ask that, I am watching changes done by using **ng-class**. This is rigth, but your watcher function is called before **ng-class** done its work. Namely you aren't watching "**ng-class**" you are watching **class** attribute. For this reason the changes you are listen will noticed to angular in the next diggest.

If you tried to access current class in your watcher, you will get old value, because ng-class hasn't done its work yet.

If you tried to access current class javascript **setTimeout** function in your in your watcher, you will get the correct vallue, because **setTimeout** would be called after all angular works done.

This case is valid for all changes outside of AngularJS. When you tried to watch an element heigth, width, color, an object property etc. You can use it in quietness.

**NOTE** Think watching changes outside of AngularJS like a promise and setTimeout would be your callback.

Comment: Are you sure using setTimeout is the appropriate way of doing this? Detecting a class change on an angular directive seems like something that should "non-hackyish" to implement.

Comment: Great it works! I was wondering if you can elaborate on why it works. Also why is the newValue and oldValue switched? I'm new to angular so I don't really get how the $digest cycle works.