# watch on getSelectedRows()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slickgrid

I have a `grid` with column of checkbox in angular controller , and I want to set a `watch` on its checkbox cells click ,

for this I use [getSelectedRows()](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#getSelectedRows) which would indicate whether the index array of the selected cell was changed .

Here is the code -

```
$scope.grid = new Slick.Grid(...)
$scope.$watch('$scope.grid.getSelectedRows()', function(newVal, oldVal){
     console.log(arguments);
});
```

but when I toggle on any of this grid checkbox  - it doesn't enter to the watcher function .

How to make it really watch to my checkbox click's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is right way

```
 $scope.$watch(funstion(){ return $scope.grid.getSelectedRows() }, function(newVal, oldVal){

    console.log(arguments);
 });
```

However it become late due to diggest cycle of angular. You may check the correct value in setTimeout function

```
$scope.$watch(funstion(){ return $scope.grid.getSelectedRows() }, function(newVal, oldVal){

    setTimeout(function(){
      var row = $scope.grid.getSelectedRows();
      //do your staff here
    },0)
 });
```

Comment: and since you're in Angular, you could use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`, not that it makes much difference but it's more Angular ;)

Comment: Be careful about using $timeout in some cases, it may couse some circular events, Yes we are in angular but we hacking angular here... You can use $timeout inside  setTimeout if you need ivoke a new diggest cycle. [Look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786814/watch-to-monitor-change-in-class-on-directive-firing-1-cycle-late/27787196#27787196)

Answer (score 0):

possibly it will suit better

```
grid.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(function(e, args){
    $scope.$emit('selectedRowsChanged', *someData*);
});

$scope.$on('selectedRowsChanged', function(*someData*){
    _do your stuff here_
})
```